# article:published_time date format

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

i save the dates via php time() format in mysql.. 
for example: 1407178292

how can i convert it to a datetime for schema/article:published_time on meta tags?

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="??" />
```

all samples i saw on net are lie this:

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2013-11-12T19:57:40+00:00" />
```

i mean: i must convert time() format to 2013-11-12T19:57:40+00:00 etc..

and also, can/should i use published_time in NewsArticle?

could someone help me?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Unix time stamp. Check out the link above. If no one posts an answer I will when I get back to my desk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `c` format option to [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is what you're looking for

```
 $date = date('c', 1407178292); // the timestamp is the second parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

Most trivially:

```
 $formatted_date = date('c', time());
```

Presuming you're on PHP5, which added support for ISO 8601 dates using the 'c' formatter.

Full documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting time in the mentioned formate then just use `date(DATE_W3C, 1407178292)` to convert date.

> `echo date(DATE_W3C, 1407178292);`

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="<?php echo date(DATE_W3C, 1407178292);?>"/>
```

for more, check https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Additionally, this would return new data on each request, so I don't think this is a good solution for the OP

Comment: @NicoHaase I edited my answer. If you can make better feel free to do so.